# Changing Facebook Liked page to a friendly URL

Tags: facebook, count, facebook-like

The way I understand FB like to work is that FB stores the url.

I want to change my webiste to have friendly URLs therefore, my old like urls (and counts) will loose their connection.

Is there a way to retain the FB like count but change all like url to be the new friendly urls?

TIA
Stu

Comment: I haven't tried it before, but try a 301 redirect of one of your links and check.

Comment: yeah, using a 301 creates an error when you "like" the page so this won't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I move a URL via 301 redirect and retain the page's Facebook likes and Open Graph information?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-move-a-url-via-301-redirect-and-retain-the-pages-facebook-likes-and-o)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible I'm afraid. All URLs need to return a 200, so you can't use a 301. This is to prevent users likes being hijacked and moved from one application or site to another